# Is my answer to this probability question right? I was told it was supposed to be really hard but it seems simple

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, expected-value

You are given an urn with 100 balls (50 black and 50 white). You pick balls from urn one by one without replacements until all the balls are out. A black followed by a white or a white followed by a black is "a color change". What number of changes is the most likely to occur?

My answer:
99, as when you make a choice that leaves 49 of other color and 50 of your chosen color. With the next choice assuming a change was made a change occurs with equal probability of remaining the same, however as this process goes on wouldn't a change occurring each time be the single most likely option?
I know Expectation for number of color changes would be 50, but I'm sort of thinking in terms of the German Tank problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your reasoning is not correct. To start with you might like to consider a smaller problem - say 3 of each colour - and list out all the possibilities (there are 20 in that case but you can use a symmetry argument to reduce the work) and count how many changes there are to see which count of changes is most common. Working that through will help you produce a correct argument, since hopefully you'll more easily see where the reasoning fails.

Comment: You might then like to look at 4 of each. You may notice a particular feature of that case.

Comment: @Glen_b Prove it by induction?

Comment: It's certainly one potential approach but I wasn't directly suggesting that to start with. I was first hoping to encourage the OP to undertake the task of building some basic  intuition of what is going on. (There's a particular point to looking at an even number of each colour case and an odd number of each colour case. Relating the two could indeed be quite fruitful but that's a later step)

Comment: @Dave Assuming I didn't make an error, this feature is what I was getting at: https://i.stack.imgur.com/woEAr.png ... since it indicates that there isn't a single mode when there's an even number of each colour. (Edit. Damn there's a typo in the title)

Comment: Another reason to think $99$ is not most likely outcome is that the probability of that is $2 \times \frac{1}{100 \choose 50} \approx 2 \times 10^{-29}$ which is a lot less than $\frac{1}{99}$

Comment: @Glen_b  You are correct about the triple.  It is a consequence of  $\frac{2}{4n \choose 2n}{2n-1 \choose n-1}^2 =\frac{2}{4n \choose 2n} {2n-1 \choose n}{2n-1 \choose n-1} =\frac{2}{4n \choose 2n}{2n-1 \choose n}^2$ as the probability of each